# Rotate a video file 90 degrees using Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, ffmpeg, video-editing

I want to use Ubuntu and preferably standard packages such as ffmpeg to rotate a .3gp video file by 90 degrees in any direction. Preferably a command line or Python script.

How can I do that?

Comment: I found that ffmpeg was able to do this. See, e.g. [Ubuntu forums: rotate video 90 degrees](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10905703#post10905703)

Comment: Also see [How to flip a video 180° (vertical/upside down) with FFmpeg?](http://superuser.com/questions/578321/how-to-flip-a-video-180%C2%B0-vertical-upside-down-with-ffmpeg)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

by using [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html), you may rotate the video by going to
Tools >> Preferences...

And select "All" for show settings. Then go to:
Video >> Filters >> Rotate

After setting the degree you want, you can rotate by going to Tools > Effects and Filters > Video Effects > Geometry .. .

[image]

the one I've tested is mp4 but I believe that [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/features.html) can support 3gp too. hope this helps. :)

Comment: i can view the video rotated, but how do you make the change persist

Comment: https://www.vlchelp.com/edit-video-apply-effects-filters-save-permanently-vlc/

Answer (score 31):

From the command-line, with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i input.3gp -filter:v transpose=1 \
-c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -crf 22 \
-c:a copy \
-metadata:s:v rotate="" \
output.3gp
```

- `transpose=1` will rotate the video 90 degrees clockwise; to rotate anti-clockwise, use `transpose=2`. See the [transpose documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#transpose) for a bit more information.
- `-metadata:s:v rotate=""` will strip any existing video stream rotation metadata; otherwise `ffmpeg` will copy it which may cause your player to apply additional unwanted rotation.
- For information on the video encoding settings here, see [this H.264 encoding guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) and [the AAC encoding guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC) if you want to re-encode the audio instead of [stream copying](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy).

Comment: This better answers the question as it explains how to do it from the command line with ffmpeg, as specified in the original question. I think this answer should be marked as correct. As of May 2017 on Fedora 25, this still works, albeit a deprecation message for the MP4 codec.

Comment: heck, it still works in 2024. i tried the vlc answer first, but in addition to the unspecified step for saving to file, it also failed to rotate the aspect ratio along with the image pixels so 40% of the image was cut off.

Answer (score 16):

There have been some changes to libav since the time that this question was originally answered. In an attempt to keep this current and useful I'll provide the followng:

You can accomplish this with recent versions of `ffmpeg` and `avconv` by using the transpose video filter.

```
avconv -i inputfile -vf transpose=clock outputfile
```

for clockwise rotation.

in ffmpeg the syntax is the same.

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile -vf transpose=clock outputfile
```

where *inputfile* is your supported input video file and *outputfile* is your desired output file.

For counter clockwise rotation replace *clock* with *cclock*

Here's an excerpt from the documentation:

```
‘cclock_flip’

    Rotate by 90 degrees counterclockwise and vertically flip. (default)
‘clock’

    Rotate by 90 degrees clockwise.
‘cclock’

    Rotate by 90 degrees counterclockwise.
‘clock_flip’

    Rotate by 90 degrees clockwise and vertically flip.
```

Sources:

- https://libav.org/avconv.html#transpose
- https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#transpose-1

Testing on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS, Ubuntu 16.04, Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Thanks for the minimal parameters. `ffmpeg` worked for me (didn't try `avconv`)

Comment: Excellent! yes many posts about `ffmpef` includes a lot of unnecessary arguments, thanks!

Comment: @MarianoRuiz I'm glad it helped you. ffmpeg is always in development so over time things change. It's not surprising that easier methods exist than some of the older answers. Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

[Avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/) should be able to do this.

Do `Video->Filters->Rotate(x degrees)->Close` then `File->Save->Save Video`

Comment: Avidemux is my go-to tool for these simple tasks that don't require a lot of customization and artistry.  Simple clipping and transforms are very easy.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know exactly what the difference is, but the top answer ffmpeg command takes a very long time to run on my computer in order to rotate a video.

This ffmpeg command on the other hand took only about 7 seconds to rotate a 2gb video file:

```
ffmpeg -i input-video.mov -metadata:s:v \ 
  rotate="-90" -codec copy output-video.mov
```

Comment: I like that no decoding/encoding is needed, done in a flash! Works great with mp4, m4v too!

Comment: This copies the video and just changes metadata so is lossless and fast. Great option and answer, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I solved a similar problem — I had a .MOV that was taken upside-down (i.e., rotated 180 degrees) which I wanted to set right.

On my Ubuntu 14.04 system, I ran `avconv` with essentially the same command-line options as given for `ffmpeg` in [evilsoup's answer](https://superuser.com/a/548018).  Apparently, it does not support a `transpose` option for 180-degree rotation, so I did the 90-degree clockwise (i.e., `transpose=1`) twice.

When I tried minimal options, I got a message to the effect that:

```
encoder 'aac' is experimental and might produce bad results.

Add '-strict experimental' if you want to use it.
```

and the output file was zero length, so I added the `-strict experimental`.

Command lines that worked were:

```
avconv -i IMG_orignl.MOV -filter:v 'transpose=1' -strict experimental IMG_interm.MOV
avconv -i IMG_interm.MOV -filter:v 'transpose=1' -strict experimental IMG_result.MOV
```

The result was satisfactory, with unexplained side-effects:

1. Intermediate file was smaller than original by ~14%.
2. Result file was smaller than intermediate by ~18% and smaller than original by almost 30%.
3. Result file shows thumbnail, while original and intermediate show merely generic icon.

Not that I'm complaining: these are desirable; I just don't understand why they came about...

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  (1) While some background information in your answer may be helpful, it’s best to focus on your solution to the problem.  I’ve edited your answer to illustrate; feel free to [edit] it further if you believe that I changed too much.  (2) The display order of answers may vary; it’s better to identify other answer(s) explicitly rather than saying “above”.  (2½) I hope you presented your `avconv` command lines in their entirety, and not just the differences from the `ffmpeg` command.  Your answer should be self-sufficient; the other answer might go away.  (3) Good luck!

Comment: Also, I assume that when you say “result was satisfactory” you mean that your “result” file *looked* as good as the original file.  You might want to ([edit] your message to) say so explicitly.  (Such information — i.e., whether you lost video quality visible to the eye — is important to your answer, and shouldn’t be hidden away in a comment.)  Also, I betcha you could leave out the quotes and say just `-filter:v transpose=1 …`.