# How to keep source frame rate with mencoder/ffmpeg?

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, mplayer, mencoder

I would like to crop and rotate a video, and then encode it to mp4 or mkv.

```
mencoder video.mp4 -vf rotate=1,crop=720:1280:0:0 -oac pcm -ovc x264 -x264encopts preset=veryslow:tune=film:crf=15:frameref=15:fast_pskip=0:threads=auto -lavfopts format=matroska -o test.mkv
```

But when I do the above encoding, the frame rate is way too fast. The encoding options were something I [found](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MEncoder#Two-pass_x264_.28very_high-quality.29), so I don't know if that is the problem.

**Question**

All I want is to crop and rotate the video, and keep the audio/video quality as good as possible.

Have anyone tried this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: input example]
[image: rotated and cropped version]
<sub>Original and transposed & cropped version</sub>

### Using `ffmpeg`

You can do this in ffmpeg. By default the input frame rate is used for the output frame rate.

Example to rotate 90° clockwise with [`transpose`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#transpose) filter and [`crop`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop) (centered) to size 720x1280:

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf "transpose=1,crop=720:1280" -c:v libx264 -c:a copy out.mkv
```

Usage of video filters requires that you re-encode the video, but audio will simply be [stream copied](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) instead of re-encoded.

### Rotate upon playback

Another option is to rotate and crop during playback. This way you do not need to re-encode and potentially reduce quality. Any player worth using should let you do this. Example using `ffplay`:

```
ffplay -vf "transpose=1,crop=720:1280" -i input
```

#### Also see:

- [How to flip a video 180° (vertical/upside down) with FFmpeg?](https://superuser.com/a/578329/110524)
- [FFmpeg and x264 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/x264EncodingGuide)