# ffmpeg rotating source video and applying overlay images

Tags: video, ffmpeg, rotate, overlay

I'm having some trouble with this, I've got a source video that has been recorded upside down. I need this video to be rotated and have a couple of transparent PNG files overlayed on top of it. I'm using this command:

`ffmpeg -i Upside_Down.mov -r 1 -i overlays_%d.png -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p -filter_complex "overlay=0:0" output.mkv`

The above command works perfectly but keeps my source video upside down obviously, I know rotation can be achieved by -vf vflip:hflip but that doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to achieve this goal or is the only option to flip the source video and apply the overlay in a second run i.e. first do `ffmpeg -i Upside_Down.mov -vf vflip:hflip` then run the code code above upon completion?

Answer (score 3):

You just need to create a [filterchain](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-syntax-1) consisting of your additional filters:

```
ffmpeg -i Upside_Down.mov -r 1 -i overlays_%d.png -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay,vflip,hflip,format=yuv420p[out]" -map "[out]" -map 0:a output.mkv
```

- I like to explicitly label the filter input and output link labels so you know exactly what is going on instead of relying on possibly unknown defaults. `[0:v]` refers to the video stream(s) of the first input (`Upside_Down.mov`), and `[1:v]` refers to the video stream(s) of the second input (`overlays_%d.png`).
- I added `-c:a copy` to [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) the audio instead of re-encoding it, but I'm unsure if `Upside_Down.mov` contains audio. This is one reason why you should always include the complete `ffmpeg` console output from your command.
- Since changing the pixel format can be performed via filtering I changed from `-pix_fmt` to the [`format` video filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format-1) so any potential conversion can occur exactly when you want it to. I did the same with `-r` and the [`fps` video filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fps-1) (but I'm not sure why you potentially change the frame rate: the console output would have been useful).
- Also see: [How to flip a video 180° (vertical/upside down) with FFmpeg?](https://superuser.com/a/578329/110524)