# Is there an easy way on mac to rotate a video 180 degrees?

Tags: macos, video

Unfortunately some important videos got recorded upside-down.  I would like the program to rotate the video 180 so it is right-side-up.

Comment: Topic was covered extensively in http://superuser.com/questions/578321/how-to-flip-a-video-180%C2%B0-vertical-upside-down-with-ffmpeg

Comment: Wow!! Thanks.  Can u merge this question?  I'm on my phone now.