# Movie rotate with Linux

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I need to rotate some movies by 90 degrees. I can remember a great old Windows app called Windows Movie Maker which is discontinued for some reason and it perfectly hit my needs. It produced a rotated movie with pretty the same quality although the output file's size was smaller than original one with no complex analysis of bit rates, audio codecs and so on.

Now I am looking for a similar solution on Linux. I tried to rotate my movies with ffmpeg or openshot but I got no rewarding results. I would like to keep my movie's quality and change the resolution accordingly, i.e from 1280x720 to 720x1280. Is this possible with some easy action? I suppose the file size should be pretty much the same after that...

Best regards

Comment: See [How to rotate a video 180° with FFmpeg?](https://superuser.com/a/578329/110524). Although you want to rotate 90° instead of 180° the methods are basically the same. As for quality use `-crf` assuming you're outputting H.264 video: see [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264).

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You are asking an off-topic question. Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Answer (score 1):

If you would prefer a GUI type of interaction with the program to perform rotation, consider [Kdenlive](https://kdenlive.org/en/) for Linux, (also for Windows) which does support rotation to any angle.

I did a quick search for "rotate video Kdenlive" and the results were substantial. I watched a 2 minute video (out of the dozen options presented) to ensure that the program will do as you require.

When you've exported the video after the rotation, you can determine the compression of the file to match your file size requirements.

The command method referenced in the comment may be more straight-forward than learning a new program, however.